# Why doesn't my Python RandomForestRegressor accurately predict training set data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm taking my baby steps with machine learning and would like to use scikit-learn's **`RandomForestRegressor()`** on a fairly complex dataset. To first get the hang of it though, I'm trying to work through a basic example as follows:

```
import sklearn.ensemble as se
import numpy as np
forest = se.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
traindata = np.arange(1000).reshape(200,5)
forest = forest.fit(traindata[0::,1::],traindata[0::,0])
```

At this point, what I think I've done is this: I've created a 200 row matrix with 5 values per row of the format `[ x, x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4 ]` where `x` is a multiple of 5 ( e.g. `[0,1,2,3,4]`, `[5,6,7,8,9]`, etc ).

I've told my forest to fit the features `[ x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4 ]` to predict **`x`**. Here's what happens when I predict though:

```
forest.predict([1,2,3,4])
>> array([2.785])
```

This is really unintuitive to me. Considering the feature values of `[1,2,3,4]` were in the training data for **`x = 0`**, shouldn't my forest be able to predict that much more closely than 2.785?

I went a step further to see the feature importance as follows:

```
forest.feature_importances_
>> array([0.26349716, 0.23664264, 0.23360533, 0.26625487])
```

Which, to me, doesn't suggest a major skew in the way I'm seeing. What am I missing here?

Comment: n.b.: one may consider a presented **( 200, 4 )** training dataSet neither to be complex nor a sufficient to train 1000 randomised decision trees. **Imagine dataSets about ( 200.000++, 300++ ) of ( mostly, not necessarily ) independent values** to get somehow a feeling of what a **RandomForest** weak-learner may grow upon.

Comment: For those wondering, I found this article helpful in understanding some of what was going on: http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-iii-random-forests/

Comment: **Yes, the series of articles**, noted in the source below **is trully of a great value** :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it does not predict precisely?

**Short version:**  due to the nature of the smart Breiman's proposed method.

**Longer version:**

Random Forests are very interesting learners.

However, you would need a bit patience to get them tuned.

```
forest.setp_param( oob_score    = True,   # set True to be able to read
                   #                      #     oob-samples score
                   random_state = 2015    # set so as to keep retesting
                   #                      #     possible / meaniningfull on
                   #                      #     an otherwise randomised
                   #                      #     learner construction
                   )
```

Principally, any attempt to use **`.fit()`** method does a lot of work behind the scene to construct a randomised set of decision trees, making it a RandomForest, working for your dataset.

The "***quality***" of **`.fit()`** is expressed in **`.oob_score_`** which shows how (in)-accurate were the already used **`oob`**-samples ( a genuine part of the Breiman's method ) after the training was finished for the given **`RandomForest`**. This helps you estimate how "***well***" or how "***poor***" does your trained `RandomForest` perform on available dataset.

The more important, however, is ( or ought be ), **how well the learner generalises** -- i.e. how well will it's predictive capability meet the reality once working on an unseen example.

This one may test via **`.score()`** method of a trained `RandomForest`-instance.

RandomForest is a "majority-vote"-predictor, to feel that, try this display of an inner-state of the army of random trees:

```
def printLDF( aPopulationSET ):
    LDF_example, LDF_counts = np.unique( aPopulationSET, return_counts = True )
    GDF_sum_scaler          = float( LDF_counts.sum() )
    for i in xrange( LDF_example.shape[0] ):
        print "{0: > 6d}: {1: > 6d} x {2: > 15.2f}            {3: > 15.4f} % {4: > 15.1f} %".format( i, LDF_counts[i], LDF_example[i], 100 * LDF_counts[i] / GDF_sum_scaler, 100 * LDF_counts[:i].sum() / GDF_sum_scaler )
    return

>>> printLDF( forest.estimators_[:].predict( anExample ) )
```

which will show you individual tree's predictions cast to the majority-vote calculus for the whole forest-based prediction.

That means, besides other things, **`RandomForest`** will principally never forecast a value "outside" of the "visited" range of values present in the training ( cannot by design "extrapolate" ).

### How to make it better?

Well, the Feature Engineering is the key. If you know a RandomForest is a feasible learner for your case and you feel it's **observed predictive powers are poor**, the feature selection is to be blamed first.

### Inspect the Forest

Inspect the learner's internal state - check what the Trees in the Forest do:

You might get a bit more insight into the model with:

```
def prediction_up_dn_intervals( aPredictorMODEL,                        # >>> http://blog.datadive.net/prediction-intervals-for-random-forests/
                                X_,                                     # aStateVECTOR: X_sampled
                                aPredictorOutputIDX =  0,               # (4,2,2) -> singleQUAD ( LONG.TP/SL, SHORT.TP/SL ) <-- idxMAP( 'LONG', 'TP', 1 )
                                aRequiredPercentile = 95
                                ):                                      
    err_dn      = []
    err_up      = []
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if len( X_.shape ) == 1:                                            # for a single X_example run
        preds   = []
        for pred in aPredictorMODEL.estimators_:
            preds.append( pred.predict( X_ )[0,aPredictorOutputIDX] )   # de-array-ification

        err_dn.append( np.percentile( preds,       ( 100 - aRequiredPercentile ) / 2. ) )
        err_up.append( np.percentile( preds, 100 - ( 100 - aRequiredPercentile ) / 2. ) )
    else:
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        for x in xrange( len( X_ ) ):                                   # for a multi X_example run
            preds   = []
            for pred in aPredictorMODEL.estimators_:
                preds.append( pred.predict( X_[x] )[0,aPredictorOutputIDX] ) # de-array-ification

            err_dn.append( np.percentile( preds,       ( 100 - aRequiredPercentile ) / 2. ) )
            err_up.append( np.percentile( preds, 100 - ( 100 - aRequiredPercentile ) / 2. ) )
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    return err_up, err_dn

#numba.jit( 'f8(<<OBJECT>>,f8[:,:],f8[:,:],i8,f8)' )                    # <<OBJECT>> prevents JIT
def getPredictionsOnINTERVAL(   aPredictorENGINE,                       # a MULTI-OBJECTIVE PREDICTOR -> a singleQUAD or a full 4-QUAD (16,0) <-(4,2,2)
                                X_,
                                y_GndTRUTH,                             # (4,2,2) -> (16,0) a MULTI-OBJECTIVE PREDICTOR
                                aPredictionIDX  =  0,                   # (4,2,2) -> singleQUAD ( LONG.TP/SL, SHORT.TP/SL ) <-- idxMAP( 'LONG', 'TP', 1 )
                                percentile      = 75
                                ):
    """
    |>>> getPredictionsOnINTERVAL( loc_PREDICTOR, X_sampled, y_sampled, idxMAP( "LONG", "TP", 1 ), 75 )     1.0                         +0:01:29.375000
    |>>> getPredictionsOnINTERVAL( loc_PREDICTOR, X_sampled, y_sampled, idxMAP( "LONG", "TP", 1 ), 55 )     0.9992532724237898          +0:03:59.922000
    |>>> getPredictionsOnINTERVAL( loc_PREDICTOR, X_sampled, y_sampled, idxMAP( "LONG", "TP", 1 ), 50 )     0.997100939998243           +0:09:16.328000
    |>>> getPredictionsOnINTERVAL( loc_PREDICTOR, X_sampled, y_sampled, idxMAP( "LONG", "TP", 1 ),  5 )     0.31375735746288325         +0:01:16.422000
    """
    correct_on_interval = 0                                                 # correct        = 0. ____________________- faster to keep asINTEGER ... +=1 and only finally make DIV on FLOAT(s) in RET
    #ruth               = y_                                                # Y[idx[trainsize:]]
    err_up, err_dn      = prediction_up_dn_intervals(   aPredictorENGINE,   # ( rf,
                                                        X_,                 #   X[idx[trainsize:]],
                                                        aPredictionIDX,     #   idxMAP( "LONG", "TP", 1 ),
                                                        percentile          #   percentile = 90
                                                        )                   #   )

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------# for a single X_ run
    if ( len( X_.shape ) == 1 ):
        if ( err_dn[0] <= y_GndTRUTH[aPredictionIDX] <= err_up[0] ):
            return 1.
        else:
            return 0.
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------# for a multi X_ run
    for i, val in enumerate( y_GndTRUTH[:,aPredictionIDX] ):            # enumerate( truth )
        if err_dn[i] <= val <= err_up[i]:
            correct_on_interval += 1
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------
    return correct_on_interval / float( y_GndTRUTH.shape[0] )           # print correct / len( truth )

def mapPredictionsOnINTERVAL(   aPredictorENGINE,                       #
                                X_,
                                y_GndTRUTH,
                                aPredictionIDX      =  0,
                                aPercentilleSTEP    =  5
                                ):
    for aPercentille in xrange( aPercentilleSTEP, 100, aPercentilleSTEP ):
        Quotient = getPredictionsOnINTERVAL( aPredictorENGINE, X_, y_GndTRUTH, aPredictionIDX, aPercentille )
        print "{0: > 3d}-percentil   {1: > 6.3f} %".format( aPercentille, 100 * Quotient )
        """
          5%  0.313757
         10%  0.420847
         15%  0.510191
         20%  0.628481
         25%  0.719758
         30%  0.839058
         35%  0.909646
         40%  0.963454
         45%  0.986603
         50%  0.997101
         55%  0.999253
         60%  0.999912
         65%  1.000000 >>> RET/JIT
         70%  1.000000 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
         75%  1.000000 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx       ???? .fit( X_, y_[:,8:12] ) # .fit() on HORIZON-T0+3???? ... y_GndTRUTH.shape[1] v/s .predict().shape[1]
        """
        if ( Quotient == 1 ):
             return
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did not know about '.oob_score_', so thank you also for that tip. I'm afraid I still don't understand a few parts of your answer, which I realize is my own ignorance but I hope you could help me out nonetheless: 1) When you say "will principally never forecast a value 'outside' of the 'visited' range of values present in the training", can you add some concrete numbers (perhaps from my example) to illustrate that? I thought regressors by their nature could do such a thing. And 2) Where do I go to learn more about Feature Engineering? I thought mine here were good..

Comment: @MrF. To complement the excellent answer here, I'd mention that the fact that a random forest regressor will never forecast a value outside of the 'visited' range of values in the training is a shortcoming that is **specific to random forest**. So you shouldn't be confused about regressors that "you thought could do such a thing": many models (linear ones for instance) can do that. Random forest can't, because of the way they work (as explained by user3666197).

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arrange'` so here is a reproducible version of your example (in general I would recommend explicitly creating separate X and Y to avoid making a stupid mistake, my first thought when seeing your question). As you can see below, a random forest classifier performs perfectly on your example within the training set. The random forest regressor does not yield perfect predictions. I am not sure why this is, but it's a place to start.

```
import numpy as np

import sklearn.ensemble as se
import numpy as np

x = 0
X_train = []
Y_train = []
while x < 1000:
    Y_train.append(x)
    X_train.append([x + 1, x + 2, + x + 3, x + 4])
    x += 5


forestregression = se.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
forestregression.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print(forestregression.predict(X_train))

[   3.005    4.96     9.015   13.875   18.9     23.985   29.18    34.24
   39.035   43.765   49.135   54.06    59.15    63.99    68.85    74.205
   79.12    84.01    88.9     93.92    98.995  104.13   108.825  114.14
  119.1    123.84   128.895  134.15   138.905  144.075  148.91   153.895
  159.165  163.83   169.065  174.195  179.03   183.975  188.915  194.06
  198.9    204.105  208.975  214.11   218.79   224.135  228.985  234.205
  239.13   244.025  249.04   254.065  258.975  264.14   269.03   274.105
  278.985  284.     288.935  294.055  299.04   304.025  308.895  313.92
  318.82   324.1    328.92   334.18   338.985  344.07   348.905  353.94
  359.115  364.11   369.     374.11   379.07   383.995  388.975  394.005
  399.035  403.91   408.99   414.125  419.165  424.17   428.86   434.14
  438.945  444.155  449.12   453.97   459.075  464.075  469.025  474.105
  478.895  483.98   489.085  494.105  498.985  504.045  508.99   514.02
  519.02   524.115  529.115  533.985  538.95   544.085  548.915  553.94
  558.935  564.035  568.925  574.12   578.925  583.995  589.21   593.99
  599.17   603.925  608.93   613.98   619.105  623.975  629.11   634.08
  638.99   644.06   648.85   654.05   659.175  664.155  669.03   673.85
  679.01   684.005  689.015  694.02   699.225  704.135  708.965  713.86
  718.88   723.84   728.99   733.835  738.985  744.205  748.99   753.74
  759.1    764.125  768.935  774.195  778.925  783.835  789.25   793.8
  798.925  804.03   809.06   813.98   819.135  823.9    828.9    834.04
  839.035  844.18   848.955  854.1    858.98   864.095  868.995  874.02
  879.165  883.795  888.905  894.245  898.965  903.8    908.98   913.945
  918.92   924.26   929.05   933.915  938.815  944.04   949.175  953.815
  959.025  963.925  968.99   974.07   979.1    984.095  988.715  992.18 ]

forestclassifier = se.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000)
forestclassifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print(forestclassifier.predict(X_train))

[  0   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85
  90  95 100 105 110 115 120 125 130 135 140 145 150 155 160 165 170 175
 180 185 190 195 200 205 210 215 220 225 230 235 240 245 250 255 260 265
 270 275 280 285 290 295 300 305 310 315 320 325 330 335 340 345 350 355
 360 365 370 375 380 385 390 395 400 405 410 415 420 425 430 435 440 445
 450 455 460 465 470 475 480 485 490 495 500 505 510 515 520 525 530 535
 540 545 550 555 560 565 570 575 580 585 590 595 600 605 610 615 620 625
 630 635 640 645 650 655 660 665 670 675 680 685 690 695 700 705 710 715
 720 725 730 735 740 745 750 755 760 765 770 775 780 785 790 795 800 805
 810 815 820 825 830 835 840 845 850 855 860 865 870 875 880 885 890 895
 900 905 910 915 920 925 930 935 940 945 950 955 960 965 970 975 980 985
 990 995]
```

Comment: Except y depends on X linearly, you can simply substract 1 from first feature and you will get y. And linear model actually performs well on this dataset.

Comment: You're right, ok well then I don't know what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Did you copy my code or manually type it in? I notice you said there was no attribute 'arrange', but my code uses 'arange' (which should be in numpy for you).

Comment: [ well, there was a typo, which I have corrected in the source code already ]

Answer (score 0):

In case you still get poor predictive performance, you can have the training set to have an equal number of class 0 and class 1 data to give more significance to signals in the data. Please refer to the [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640065/machine-learning-training-test-data-split-method) for further explanations.

Answer (score -1):

There are several things you're doing wrong/suboptimally:

- you have only 200 rows/observations, yet you try to train N=1000 trees. That makes no sense. You should have no. trees << no. observations. Anywhere from N=3-40 trees.
- **You are trying to learn a line: your data is perfectly linear (whereas RF's are intended for a normally-distributed response variable).** For linear data, using a more suited classifier like linear regression would outperform RF and give perfect results (in fact all your four features are linearly dependent, you could throw away any three columns, and regression would still give perfect results)
- Then, you're trying to **predict at one of the endpoints**, which is an issue known to incur bias, for the following reason. Consider that the RF is an ensemble of 1000 trees whose rows are randomly chosen; some trees won't contain those bottom observations [1,2,3,4] or [6,7,8,9] or [11,12,13,14] or [16,17,18,19] hence necessarily can't possibly predict the bottom endpoint right (this wouldn't be so much of a problem if it was in the tail of a normal distribution). The output prediction will be an average of individual prediction from each tree in the ensemble:

  `for i in range(1000):
      forest.estimators_[i].predict([1,2,3,4])`

or: `np.hstack([ forest.estimators_[i].predict([1,2,3,4]) for i in range(1000) ])`

then you will see many 0s and 5s, some 10s, but even some 15s, 20s and 25s. So your final prediction will be some number >0 and probably <5.