# Machine Learning Training & Test data split method

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data, confusion-matrix

I was running a random forest classification model and initially divided the data into train (80%) and test (20%). However, the prediction had too many False Positive which I think was because there was too much noise in training data, so I decided to split the data in a different method and here's how I did it.

Since I thought the high False Positive was due to the noise in the train data, I made the train data to have the equal number of target variables. For example, if I have data of 10,000 rows and the target variable is 8,000 (0) and 2,000 (1), I had the training data to be a total of 4,000 rows including 2,000 (0) and 2,000 (1) so that the training data now have more signals.

When I tried this new splitting method, it predicted way better by increasing the Recall Positive from 14 % to 70%.

I would love to hear your feedback if I am doing anything wrong here. I am concerned if I am making my training data biased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have unequal number of data points in each classes in training set, the baseline (random prediction) changes.

By noisy data, I think you want to mean that number of training points for class 1 is more than other. This is not really called noise. It is actually bias.

For ex: You have 10000 data point in training set, 8000 of class 1 and 2000 of class 0. I can predict class 0 all the time and get 80% accuracy already. This induces a bias and baseline for 0-1 classification will not be 50%.

To remove this bias either you can intentionally balance the training set as you did or you can change the error function by giving weight inversely proportional to number of points in training set.

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response. So the method I implemented (having the training data to have 50% class 0 and 50% class 1) is a correct method to use?

Comment: Yes! but it depends on how much importance you give to false positives or false negative. For ex: let class 1 be that patient has cancer and 0 be not cancer. You would be more averse to false negative compared to false positives. In that case, you would give different importance to different classes predicted. But if you want to give equal weight to both 0 and 1, then it is correct.

PS : Accept the answer, if you think its correct/satisfactory

Comment: The cancer example is exactly the case for me where I want to have less False Negative! So should I give more weights to class 1 than class 0 instead of having training data to have 50% class 1 and 50% class 0?

Comment: Yes, in that case I would want give more error weight to false negatives and keep training data unbiased (50-50). Because making it unbiased (not 50-50) is same as giving different weights. 
"More % of one class is roughly equivalent to more weight to that class"

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that (80-20) balanced data is biased if we agree that bias is "is the difference between this estimator's expected value and the true value of the parameter being estimated." (Wiki). The testing data is likely to have the same distribution as the training data - if well distributed. And the estimator real value has no reason to be (50-50), so neither the training data. Consider cancer : if your training set is all the human on earth - except some that are the testing - you don't expect half of the testing data to have cancer, so neither the training distribution

Comment: I agree with you @IgorOA. But in that we should give different weights to diffferent errors and train with those errors as feedback instead of 0-1 error. And the learned model should not be judged on the overall accuracy, but its performance false negative or/and false positive of particular class.

Comment: So, the whole point is error function should be designed such that it can take care of skew in data as well as required confusion matrix

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you did is right and this process is something similar to **"Stratified sampling"**.
In your first model,where accuracy was very low the model did not get enough correlations between features and target for positive class(1).Also it model might have somewhat over-fitted for negative class.This is called "High bias -High variance" situation.

"Stratified sampling" is nothing but when you are extracting a sample data from a big population,you make sure that all classes will have some what approximately equal proportion to make the model's training assumptions more accurate and reliable.

In the second case model was able to correlate relationships between features and target and positive and negative class characteristics was well distinguishable.
Eliminating noise is a part of data preparation that should be obviously done before putting data into a model.